# NSDateFormatterFullStyle api is giving different results

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

NSDateFormatterFullStyle api is giving different date formats in iPod and iPhone. In
iPhone : Friday, 21 December 2012 (coma is missed)
iPod   : Friday, 21 December, 2012.

Sample code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[postdateText doubleValue] / 1000.0];
NSLog(@"date %@:",date);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
 NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CST"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:tz];
return dateString;


// I was tried in this way as well
//[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY"];
//[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```

Comment: Check the locale set in the devices.

Comment: Where it is locale in device settings, i am not able to found @coder284

Comment: Thank U @coder284 for the quick response and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

That is changing depends on region format as well as language. Go to settings->General->International->Region Format. It should work.